# ANTLR rule to consume fixed number of characters

Tags: parsing, serialization, antlr

I am trying to write an ANTLR grammar for the PHP serialize() format, and everything seems to work fine, except for strings. The problem is that the format of serialized strings is :

```
s:6:"length";
```

In terms of regexes, a rule like `s:(\d+):".{\1}";` would describe this format if only backreferences were allowed in the "number of matches" count (but they are not).

But I cannot find a way to express this for either a lexer or parser grammar: the whole idea is to make the number of characters read depend on a backreference describing the number of characters to read, as in Fortran Hollerith constants (i.e. `6HLength`), not on a string delimiter.

This example from the [ANTLR grammar for Fortran](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1183077163756/f77-antlr2.g) seems to point the way, but I don't see how. Note that my target language is Python, while most of the doc and examples are for Java:

```
// numeral literal
ICON {int counter=0;} :
    /* other alternatives */
    // hollerith
    'h' ({counter>0}? NOTNL {counter--;})* {counter==0}?
      {
      $setType(HOLLERITH);
      String str = $getText;
      str = str.replaceFirst("([0-9])+h", "");
      $setText(str);
      }
    /* more alternatives */
    ;
```

Answer (score 5):

Since input like `s:3:"a"b";` is valid, you can't define a `String` token in your lexer, unless the first and last double quote are **always** the start and end of your string. But I guess this is not the case.

So, you'll need a lexer rule like this:

```
SString
  :  's:' Int ':"' ( . )* '";'
  ;
```

In other words: match a `s:`, then an `integer` value followed by `:"` then one or more characters that can be anything, ending with `";`. But you need to tell the lexer to stop consuming when the value `Int` is not reached. You can do that by mixing some plain code in your grammar to do so. You can embed plain code by wrapping it inside `{` and `}`. So first convert the value the token `Int` holds into an integer variable called `chars`:

```
SString
  :  's:' Int {chars = int($Int.text)} ':"' ( . )* '";'
  ;
```

Now embed some code inside the `( . )*` loop to stop it consuming as soon as `chars` is counted down to zero:

```
SString
  :  's:' Int {chars = int($Int.text)} ':"' ( {if chars == 0: break} . {chars = chars-1} )* '";'
  ;
```

and that's it.

A little demo grammar:

```
grammar Test;

options {
  language=Python;
}

parse
  :  (SString {print 'parsed: [\%s]' \% $SString.text})+ EOF
  ;

SString
  :  's:' Int {chars = int($Int.text)} ':"' ( {if chars == 0: break} . {chars = chars-1} )* '";'
  ;

Int
  :  '0'..'9'+
  ;
```

*(note that you need to escape the `%` inside your grammar!)*

And a test script:

```
import antlr3
from TestLexer import TestLexer
from TestParser import TestParser

input = 's:6:"length";s:1:""";s:0:"";s:3:"end";'
char_stream = antlr3.ANTLRStringStream(input)
lexer = TestLexer(char_stream)
tokens = antlr3.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = TestParser(tokens)
parser.parse()
```

which produces the following output:

```
parsed: [s:6:"length";]
parsed: [s:1:""";]
parsed: [s:0:"";]
parsed: [s:3:"end";]
```